# Git does not ask for a password: ! [remote rejected] (permission denied)

Tags: git

Push to remote https://github.com/fork5/repo says:

```
! [remote rejected] master -> master (permission denied)
```

Git does not ask for a password.  Why is permission denied?

Push to remote https://github.com/wolfv6/repo.git works as expected.

From the Linux terminal:

```
$ git push origin
Counting objects: 2, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 233 bytes | 233.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 2 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/fork5/repo.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (permission denied)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/fork5/repo.git'

$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/fork5/repo.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/fork5/repo.git (push)
upstream    https://github.com/wolfv6/repo.git (fetch)
upstream    https://github.com/wolfv6/repo.git (push)

$ cat ~/.git-credentials
https://wolfv6:redacted@github.com
```

Comment: Do you have permission to push to that remote?

Comment: I am the owner.  Where to set the permission?

Comment: Is it the same account which owns them?

Comment: I own both accounts https://github.com/fork5 and https://github.com/wolfv6

Answer (score 0):

Your origin remote is missing the ".git" at the end.

Comment: Good catch.  I added ".git" to the end but still same error.  The question is updated.